# Custom post type not pulling CSS

Tags: custom-post-types, css, advanced-custom-fields, page-template

I created a page template for CPT but the it's not pulling up the CSS. Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: How are your page templates meant to pull in the CSS? Nothing about a page template will pull in CSS unless you explicitly program it to

Comment: more detail please. front end or back end admin?